# Deploy the ionic app on ios with github actions

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, code-signing, github-actions

I'm trying to build a project using Gitgub actions on macos, and I can't add an authorization key, the build command in xcode gives me this error:
`** ARCHIVE FAILED ** error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'App' from project 'App') error: No profiles for '' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching ''. (in target 'App' from project 'App')`

this is my code:

```
 - name: Build ipa
    run: ionic capacitor build ios --release --prod --no-open

 - name: Import Codesign Certificate
    uses: Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs@v1
    with:
      p12-file-base64: ${{secrets.IOS_DISTRIBUTION_P12_CER}}
      p12-password: ${{secrets.DIST_CERT_P12_PASSWORD}}

- name: Archive
    run: xcodebuild -workspace ios/App/App.xcworkspace
      -scheme App clean archive -configuration release
      -sdk iphoneos -allowProvisioningUpdates DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=${{secrets.APPLE_TEAM_ID}} -archivePath ios/App/App.xcarchive
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first setup the provisioning profiles for your app:
You can use the action for this to automatically download them:

https://github.com/Apple-Actions/download-provisioning-profiles